# A tidy way in R to create new rows and append to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I want to add "empty" data rows to an existing data frame in R. Why? For data entry by users in my R web application.

I found this solution, using base methods in R.

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, rep, df$ntimes))
```

I wanted a cleaner, "tidy" method.

Answer (score 2):

`bind_rows()` fills in missing columns with `NA`, so you can do this by adding a table that has only an `id` column.

```
library(dplyr)

# Example table
customer <- tibble(
   id = c(1, 2), 
   name = c("Stephen", "Samantha"),
   destination = c("Kona", "Rome")
)

new_rows_requested <- 100

add_rows <- tibble(id = max(customer$id) + 1:new_rows_requested)
customer <- bind_rows(customer, add_rows)
```

Comment: Interesting.  This is cleaner to read.  But it shows NA in all the new rows.  So, for a limited number of columns, this can be cleaned up (non-technical users may find NA confusing.)  So adding `%>%
   mutate(name = ifelse(is.na(name), "", name),
          destination = ifelse(is.na(destination), "", destination))` to the end cleans up the NAs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean way to add rows to an existing data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

customer <- tibble(
   id = c(1, 2), 
   name = c("Stephen", "Samantha"),
   destination = c("Kona", "Rome")
)

new_rows_requested <- 100

add_rows <- tibble(
    id = NA, name = "", destination = ""
  ) %>% 
  slice(rep(1:1, each = new_rows_requested)) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number() + max(customer$id))

customer <- bind_rows(customer, add_rows)
```

Hope this is helpful for others. Interested to see other approaches as well.